# Quartz scheduler - external Trigger configuration through AdoJobStore and Clustering

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Exploring (Ado)JobStore (data base job store in general) I met subjects like clustering, load balancing and sharing jobs' work data state across multiple applications.
But I think I didn't find a JobStore subject that covers my scenario.

I need to run Quartz Jobs in Windows Service and I need to be able to change configuration of Triggers in other application (in Admin panel in web application) and the Triggers to be applied by the Quartz in my Windows Service automatically (Quartz tracks changes and applies them).

Is it possible to do this by using AdoJobStore/Clustering mechanism? I mean in terms of JobStore's features, so by using Quartz scheduler API. Not by using SQL and changing data in Quartz tables directly or any other workarounds (according to Quartz's Best Practices doc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quartz.NET scheduler can be accessed [remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480787/get-an-instance-of-the-scheduler-that-is-being-run-on-a-windows-service/26482361#26482361), independently of job stores. Since you already have a web app you can add a reference to the remote scheduler and use the API to administer jobs, triggers etc.