# Quartz schedulers controlled from an external app

Tags: scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, scheduler, quartz.net

I am currently working on Quartz.NET (version 2.3.1). I have created different Schedulers with different jobs using the code below (for each scheduler):

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "QuartzSchedulerTest";
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = AUTO;
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false";
properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "myConnString"
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";

// Get scheduler
ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler scheduler = sf.GetScheduler();
```

Now I have all scheduling information stored on a SQL database and everything works.

I created a new Console Application because I need to manage all schedulers (get schedulers list, jobs for each scheduler, send command to pause and resume triggers ecc...).
This is the code I wrote to try to have handlers to all existing schedulers:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false";
properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "myConnString"
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";

// Get scheduler
ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
var schedulers = sf.AllSchedulers;
```

But no handlers returned (schedulers count is 0). Can anyone tell me how can I get all schedulers? Is it possible?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to access the schedulers [remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480787/get-an-instance-of-the-scheduler-that-is-being-run-on-a-windows-service/26482361#26482361)

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to each scheduler instance directly using remoting. The schedulers are not aware of each other and there is no way to get a list of all of the schedulers that are in a cluster.

Once you connect to each scheduler then you'll be able to pull a list of running jobs and manipulate the job schedule as necessary. If all of the schedulers are in a cluster, then you don't have to connect to all of them to manipulate the jobs themselves. You can do that from any of the instances. However, the list of running jobs has to be compiled by asking each scheduler individually.